# redirect to my login page if not logged in

Tags: users, login

When a customer wants to leave a review on the product page, they are prompted to log in if not.
Do you have a proposal to send the customer to the a specific login page and then return once logged in?
I tried this but without success, I am still sent to my account page.

```php
add_filter(‘login_url’, ‘custom_login_url’, 10, 3);

function custom_login_url( $login_url, $redirect, $force_reauth ) {

$login_page_id = get_permalink(woocommerce_get_page_id(‘login’));

return get_permalink( $login_page_id );

}
```

Comment: How are you prompting the user to log in if they're not already logged in? If you're redirecting users to WordPress's login URL, using [`wp_login_url()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_login_url/), you can send the URL you want them to return to (once they're logged in) as the `$redirect` parameter.

Comment: Lorsque le client se trouve sur la page produit et qu'il souhaite laisser un avis il alors est invité à se connecter.
Je ne souhaite pas envoyer le client vers l'URL de connexion de Wordpress mais bien vers la page "Login" créée à cet effet et ensuite revenir sur la page produit.

Comment: OK, if you're using a custom login page, you're either writing your own code—in which case you should be able to pass along the product page's URL in the querystring—or you're using a plugin, in which case you should contact the plugin's support team about this. Third-party plugin support is [off topic](/help/on-topic) here. (Aussi: je sais parler français, mais WPSE est un site anglais. Si tu ne parles pas anglais, je recommande d'utiliser Google Translate, que vous avez utilisé, je crois, pour votre question.)

Comment: I'm sorry, here is the translation of my previous comment.
When the customer is on the product page and wishes to leave a review, He is invited to log in.
 I do not want to send the customer to the Wordpress connection URL but rather to the "Login" page created for this purpose and then return to the product page. 

I want to write my own code and I am not using a plugin in this case.